# Finding id with specific condition in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website with BeautifulSoup in Python

I'd like to find all the `a href` with `id` starts with "des "(with space at the tail) + '3-4 letters'

I just tried:

```
bsObj.findAll("a",{"id":"des "})
```

But it does not find what I originally intended to.

Do I need to use regex or something?

I would appreciate all your helps. Thanks.

```
<div>
    <a id="des 6TN" href="/en-kr/shop/men/11-by-boris-bidjan-saberi?lvrid=_gm_d6tn">
        11 BY BORIS BIDJAN SABERI
    </a>
    <br/>
    <a id="des R6L" href="/en-kr/shop/men/11-eleven?lvrid=_gm_dr6l">
        11 ELEVEN
    </a>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go the *regex* route, you can pass a compiled regex pattern to the `id` parameter like so (added an irrelevant/unmatch `a` tag for demonstration purpose):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
​
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div><a id="des 6TN" href="/en-kr/shop/men/11-by-boris-bidjan-saberi?
lvrid=_gm_d6tn">11 BY BORIS BIDJAN SABERI</a><br /><a id="des R6L" href="/en-
kr/shop/men/11-eleven?lvrid=_gm_dr6l">11 ELEVEN</a><a id="ds R6L" href="/en-
kr/shop/men/11-eleven?lvrid=_gm_dr6l">11 ELEVEN</a><br />""")

soup.find_all('a', id=re.compile('^des \w{3,4}$'))

#[<a href="/en-kr/shop/men/11-by-boris-bidjan-saberi?
# lvrid=_gm_d6tn" id="des 6TN">11 BY BORIS BIDJAN SABERI</a>, <a href="/en-
# kr/shop/men/11-eleven?lvrid=_gm_dr6l" id="des R6L">11 ELEVEN</a>]
```

Comment: It is really perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way (not using regex) I don't like regular expressions where I don't need them necessary.

```
all_des = soup.findAll('a')
#list of every <a> tag

for i in all_des: #loops through all
    if i.has_attr('id') and i['id'].startswith('des'): 
# check if there is an id within the <a> and if the id starts with des.
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
<a href="/en-kr/shop/men/11-by-boris-bidjan-saberi?lvrid=_gm_d6tn" id="des 6TN">
        11 BY BORIS BIDJAN SABERI
    </a>
<a href="/en-kr/shop/men/11-eleven?lvrid=_gm_dr6l" id="des R6L">
        11 ELEVEN
    </a>
```

Hopefully, that answers your question, the method above by the awesome '@Psidom' is maybe more convenient to you but I'm pretty confident that pythons inbuilt methods are faster than using regular expressions. Where the regex `'^des \w{3,4}$'`:

> `**^** asserts position at start of the string
>   des  matches the characters des  literally (case sensitive)`
>
> `**\w{3,4}** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])`
>
> `**{3,4}** Quantifier — Matches between 3 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)`
>
> `**$** asserts position at the end of the string`

Comment: I really appreciate for your kindness!
And it works so perfectly!

Comment: Thank you, you're far too kind. I just wanted to make sure you'd understand how it works not just that it works. 
Please don't forget to check make the nike sign and mark an answer to your question whether it's the one by 'Psidom' or mine. 
Also if you have any other questions don't hesitate just type something in the comment and edit your question that is if you need any additional help :)